# In C/C++ is is possible to export a linker symbol for an offset inside a struct?

Tags: c, linker, symbol-table

In one file I have a struct like...

```
struct t {
    int private;
    int public;
};

struct t s;
```

One way to have other object files be able to access `s.public` would be to put...

```
struct t {
    int private;
    int public;
};

extern struct t s;
```

...into a header file and the have the other files reference `s.public`.

I'd like to avoid this because it locks in the offset between between the base of `s` and the base of `public` in any object files that reference `s.public`. This means that these files would have the wrong address for `public` if I ever added a new `private2` after `private` it would require a recompile.

Instead I'd like to find a way to export the location of symbol `s.public` as maybe `s_public_direct` directly rather than as `s` with an offset to `public. So other files would then only need the header...

```
extern int s_public_direct;
```

...and would have no knowledge of the layout (or even existence) of the structure that `public` happens to live in.

Is there any way to export a symbol reference for a variable that lives inside a structure in C/C++? If not, is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

Note that is not a scoping issue so marking `private` with C++ `private:` would not change the fact that the referencing object file would still get passed the base address of the enclosing struct and then would add the offset to get to `public`. I am really looking for some kind of C/C++ syntax that tells the compiler to export a symbol of a variable that is in inside a struct. Or maybe a way to declare a new exportable symbol like `int s_public_direct` as an alias for the variable inside the struct.

Comment: You haven't said why you think you need to do this - for example, why is the struct instance global?

Comment: Is it worth to not recompile it? Anyway, I think it would be possible, if you do the memory management by yourself instead by the struct. So you create a centralized byte array an some class, which alllows access to some of the bytes.

Comment: You might be able to make use of the `offsetof` macro from `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth this is to implement shared memory as a way for a bootloader and application to communicate with each other.

Comment: @tangoal one of the files must be very specially compiled so can only be distributed in pre-compiled object form.

Comment: @SteveSummit, this looks promising! Maybe I could add the offset to the base of the `s` global and then use something like the gcc `at` __attribte_ to fix a new `int` at the same address as the computed address of `s.public`? I'll give it try! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to keep the type opaque and export accessor funtion(s) for the field:

```
extern int get_t_public(struct t *);
extern void set_t_public(struct t *, int);
```

This allows you to also export it read-only (by defining the get without the set), or a variety of other useful things (enforcing some constraints on the value, or caching things dependent on them and invalidating the cache when the value changes and things need to be recomputed.)

Comment: On this platform it is not possible to call code across files since the files live in different kinds of memory (one is application and one is bootloader), so I can only share data in fixed locations in RAM.